# How does merge replication work with SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication, sql-server-compact

I have been trying out merge replication with SQL Server databases, and was just wondering how merge replication works on SQL Server CE?

For instance merge replication with SQL Server databases normally relies on triggers, and SQL Server CE doesn't have any triggers.

Also do tables such as `MSmerge_conflicts_info` and `sysmergesubscriptions` etc exist with the SQL Server CE version of merge replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact has a built-in change tracking mechanism (similar to SQL Server Change Tracking), and when a database file is merge replicated, a number of system tables are added to the database, see [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlservercompact/merge-replication-system-tables) - conflicts are only handled on ther server side. In addition to the tables mentioned in the blog post, some _sys columns are also added to each merge replicated table.